# Chrome Extension Not posting Data using Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension which grabs the current tab url and post it to the server(PHP).
Here is my manifest file:

```
{
"name": "testApp",
"version": "0.0.0.1",
"description": "test Description",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "test.ico",
"default_title": "Test"
},
"background_page": "background.html",
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js"]
    }
  ],
"permissions": [
"tabs","http://localhost/"
]
}
```

This is my background.html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var url = tab.url
    postUrl(url);
});
function postUrl(url){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/savetodb.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{ name: "xyz", time: "3pm",url: url },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

It sends request to the **savetodb.php** where I printing **$_POST** using `print_r()`. but it is printing `Array ( )`.
I'm not getting what is the Issue and how can I solve that.. 
Thanks ...

Comment: Do you tried `$.post` function instead of `$.ajax` ?

Comment: @Lian> Showing same result `Array ( )`

Comment: @Ravi, in your network tab of Developer Tools, do see see the variables in the request?

Comment: @Lian Yes, it is showing name,time and url with their values.

Comment: I've made a test with your code, Chrome 22.0.1229.79, jQuery 1.7.2, a distant apache server running PHP 5.3.16 (not localhost), and it worked. My PHP file only contained `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`. Maybe there's a problem with your PHP config? (just guessing...)

Comment: but normal php page are showing the data.